# Gradle Local Dependency Testing

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, gradle, dependencies, dependency-management

I have 3 gradle projects, projectA, projectB, projectC. All of which build a jar file named projectX-0.0.0.jar. On my jenkins server, all of these projects deploy these jars to my companies artifactory.

In projectA, I have multiple compile dependencies used throughout my entire project. Then in project B, I include project A by stating: `compile group: 'com.company.projectName', name: 'projectA, version '0.0.0'` So I can use these dependencies (i.e. slf4j) I do the same for projectC to include projectB dependencies, which in result includes projectA's dependencies.

This works great for our jenkins servers on deployment, after I have pushed the code to the server, however when trying to test locally I can not get the dependencies to update for testing my code.

I have tried:

1. Updating the gradle cache that downloads project A from artifactory with locally built project A jar. Located in `C:/users/username/.gradle/caches/path-to-jar`.
2. Removed the `compile group: 'com.company.projectName', name: 'projectA, version '0.0.0'` and replaced it with `compile files('libs/projectA-0.0.0.jar')`, placing projectA's jar within a lib folder in projectB
3. Using gradle offline mode in IntelliJ and repeating #1
4. Going offline completely on my pc and repeating #1

With all 4 attempts above I still have not been able to resolve dependencies declared in project A for project B.

My goal is to be able to update a compile,testCompile,runtime,etc. dependency in my projectA.gradle file, and then run my projects down my pipeline to ensure this update effects the dependencies in my project as I intended.

Comment: It sounds like you are describing a use case for [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html).

Comment: I already have a working project using this setup. My description is asking how to test locally.

Comment: See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:dynamic_versions_and_changing_modules, https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:controlling_caching, https://discuss.gradle.org/t/configuring-gradle-project-to-always-refresh-dependencies-in-the-gradle-cache/6024/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the .jar and .pom file within your gradle cache. The .jar file contains the source code while the pom contains the dependencies you brought in the previous project. Using a `gradlew clean build install` you can create the jar and the pom.

So to solve your problem, do a `gradle build clean install` on project-a. Grab the jar and pom from the build file generated and replace the project-a.jar and project-a.pom within the cache. Then do the same for project-b and you will see the changes in project-c after a gradle refresh.